# Minimum number of samples required for an approximately right machine learning algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, sample-size, small-sample

I was asked this question in an interview based on the fact that Machine Learning was mentioned in my resume. And this is the question that I was given,

> Lets say you want to make a prediction with any
> algorithm(ML/statistical), what is the minimum sample size required to
> make sure that your prediction is reliable?

I answered on grounds of the complexity of algorithm and other factors. But they were looking for my knowledge about a specific formula which dictates it. My friend did ask me to look up about PAC learnability. But I still need clarity if that is the actual answer they wanted.
Statistics does have a theorem which asks for 30 samples minimum and another formula which goes by this formula to calculate the sample size for stats.[image]

Yes, Machine learning does stem from statistics, but do we have any particular theorem/ formula based approach to answer this question

Comment: This goes into prediction uncertainty and bias-variance tradeoff.

Comment: I'd say the answer is 1, without defining what is meant by "reliable". The more data you have, the less uncertain your model is, but there is no point at which you can be *sure* that your model is *absolutely* reliable independant of the particular problem.  I'm not sure asking for knowledge of a specific formula is a good way to interview a candidate, a good candidate can learn a formula from a book in a short time, but knowing one formula well does not make you a good candidate.